# Changing source of Excel Pivot Table from Sheet Range to SQL Query using VBA and ADO

Tags: excel, ado, ms-access-2010

A sheet has several Pivot Tables. Currently, the source data for the Pivot Table is being retrieved from an Access Table using ADO and populated in a sheet. The Range in the sheet is then used as the source for the Pivot Table. I am trying to change the source of the Pivot Table to an SQL Query (i.e. Select * from a Table) directly from MS-Access.  The following code runs fine (the Connectionstring is returned by a function and is shown below the code).

```
Sub PivotTableDataADO()
'Late Binding
Dim strConnectString        As String
Dim cn           As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim qry             As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pvc As PivotCache
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DashBoard")
'Connect Database
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
qry = "SELECT * FROM CallData;"
cn.Open AccessCode.strConnectString
rs.Open qry, cn
Set pvc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlExternal)
Set pvc.Recordset = rs

For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
pt.PivotCache.SourceData = rs
pt.PivotCache.Refresh
pt.RefreshTable
Next pt

End Sub
```

The code fails at the line "pt.PivotCache.SourceData = rs"  with the error message "Wrong number of arguments. Have experimented with other properties of the PivotCache without luck.

The ConnectionString is:
strConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\rspai.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxx;

How can I correct the issue and make the SQL Query as the SourceData for the existing Pivot Tables? I am okay with another approach too.

Thanks in Advance for the help.